Position and displacement vector in Arc coordinate system
In Arc coordinate system the position of the particle is given by the length of the path(which is pre-determined and may also be curved) that it has travelled so how can we write it's position vector and displacement vector in this coordinate system?

the position vector is $~\vec P=\left[~x(s)~,y(s),z(s)~\right]^T~$ where s is the arc length
